# how will split my value sets by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this: `28_34/42/34,23_21/67/12,63_5/6/56`. I would like to split or remove sets by the id e.g. `23` then `23_21/67/12` should be removed.

I would check after comma and before underscore the value and its should be removed all sets of this value from sting. I have used this code:

```
<input id="allcartds" value ="28_34/42/34,23_21/67/12,63_5/6/56">
```

```js
var ds_id = "23";
$("#allcartds").val(function(i, v) {
    return $.grep(v.split(','), function(value) {  
        return value != ds_id;  
    }).join(',');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var ds_id = "23";
$("#allcartds").val(function(i, v) {
    return $.grep(v.split(','), function(value) {  
        return value.split('_')[0] != ds_id;  
    }).join(',');
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot my friend . Thats was awesome for me .

Comment: If worked, accepted my answer by click mark beside answer and upvote if you like. Welcome from SO.